# Can we excecute WHERE conditions inside WHERE clause where if a condition is not met inside it then the parser continues onto the next condition, sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to have my sql statement to evaluate everything in the `WHERE` condition and not stop if a condition is not met. I see that `CASE WHEN` stops when the first matched statement returns true.

So similar to below only evaluate the `THEN` part if our `WHEN` condition is met and not stop if the condition is met.

Any way to do this?

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM users AS u 
JOIN microposts m ON u.id=m.user_id 
WHERE CASE WHEN #{my_string} != '' THEN u.gender = #{my_string} 
WHEN #{my_string2} != '' THEN u.hometown = #{my_string2} 
WHEN #{my_string3} != '' THEN m.content = #{my_string3} 
END
```

Comment: It's generally better to user AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're actually looking for is an `AND/OR` structure, where all the conditions are `AND`ed together but we use `OR #{my_string} == ''` to bypass a condition when the string is not specified:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM users AS u 
JOIN microposts m ON u.id=m.user_id 
WHERE ( #{my_string}  = '' OR u.gender   = #{my_string} )
  AND ( #{my_string2} = '' OR u.hometown = #{my_string2} )
  AND ( #{my_string3} = '' OR m.content  = #{my_string3} )
```

Comment: Ok. Yeah I just read up on the brackets. Quite easy in the end. I believe I could still use `AND` in place of the `OR` inside the brackets

Comment: @LeeEather no, using `AND` inside the brackets wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok, sorry I get it now. Yeah as I thought. Its a bit contrived. Possibly because sql is designed to be read left to right

Comment: I will add the `==` should be just `=` but even I wrote `==` lol

Comment: @LeeEather LOL indeed! I can't believe I did that. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM users AS u 
JOIN microposts m ON u.id=m.user_id 
WHERE ( #{my_string} != '' AND u.gender = #{my_string} )
OR ( #{my_string2} != '' AND u.hometown = #{my_string2} )
OR ( #{my_string3} != '' AND m.content = #{my_string3} )
```

This will find records where any of the three conditions holds.

Comment: Beaten by 15 sec :( removed mine :)

Comment: Ok. But I believe `OR` returns any records that match between the `OR` where as I would like it to be `AND`. So if `( #{my_string} != '' AND u.gender = #{my_string} )` evaluates to false, still match all other true conditions